# Can I fire Phaser 3 events from DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, events, phaser-framework

I'm trying to fire a Phaser 3 event from DOM like I read on this example I found on internet:
"The game instance is accessible when you create the game, with something like
`const game = new Phaser.Game(config);`
And you can access everything from your desired scene from this instance
`const scene = game.scene.keys.sceneName`
And do something like

```
textareaElement.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    const text = textareaElement.value;
    scene.updateGameTextFromTextarea(text);
});
```

This is my project config:

```
const config = {
    // Phaser.AUTO, intenta usar WebGL y si el navegador no lo  tiene, usa canva.
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    parent: 'game-container',
    width: 650,
    height: 522,
    scene: [MainScene], 
    scale: {
        mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT
    },
    dom: {
        createContainer: true
    },
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
        // debug: true,
        // gravity: { y: 350 }
        }
    }
}

// Inicializacion del objeto
game = new Phaser.Game(config)`
```

I actually can access to game from console, but can´t fire events.

```
const scene = game.scene.keys.MainScene
scene.greeting()
```

get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'greeting')
> at :1:7

Code:
https://github.com/Neffer2/bull-rompecabezas.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

The first issue is, that the name of the scene is `gameScene` not `MainScene` , *this is the value from the constructor*.

The second issue is the Scene/Game Instance is not populated right away, you would have to wait abit. I simulated this in the demo with the `setTimeout`, or you can also click the `Button` to call the same function from the scene.

**Here a short Demo:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

class MainScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor(){
        super('gameScene');
    } 
    
    test(){
        console.info('Hello From Scene');
    }
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {            
            gravity:{ y: 100 },
            debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: [ MainScene ],
    banner: false
}; 

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

setTimeout( () => game.scene.keys.gameScene.test(), 1000);  // Wait for generation

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => game.scene.keys.gameScene.test())
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>

<button id="button"> Fire from the DOM </button><br>
```

Comment: Omg can't belive it was a wrong name ‍♂️
Well, I have learned a lot in a short time thanks to your explanation .
Thank you so much.

Comment: @NefferBarragan Sure thing, we all made similar mistakes a the begining, it will get better. :) Btw.: If possible and your question is solved, could you accept my answer by clicking the checkmark next to the upvote arrows. Thanks in advance and have fun with phaser

Comment: Sorry I made the change as soon as I read your answer and forgot to mark it.
Thank you very much again